# Возможно ли настроить получение отчетов из Google Play на почту?

Tags: google-play

Хотел бы получить получать отчет из Google Play о загрузках, пользователях и прочем за сутки на почту ежедневно. Возможно ли это настроить средствами Google или стороннего сервиса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовался AppAnnie, сервис импортирует статистику и отправляет сводку на почту.